# possible xml elements in Android resources xmls?

Tags: xml, android, resources

I recently came across a forum post in the android developers group. (link below)
  http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ef3bdebcb715b385

It has one post which contains following xml. It is xml file which can be used in drawable folder.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
android:state_pressed="false"
android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
android:state_pressed="false"
android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />

<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focus"
/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focus"/>

<!-- Pressed -->
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_press" />
</selector>
```

Now my question is, where is the documentation which tells me that i can use the following xml tags 
`<selector> , <item>, <color>, <integer-array>, <string-array>` and many others tag to create xml resources...?

I hope, i have explained what i want to know ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where is the documentation which tells
>   me that i can use the following xml
>   tags `<selector>` , `<item>`, `<color>`,
>   `<integer-array>`, `<string-array>` and
>   many others tag to create xml
>   resources

Unfortunately, there is no such documentation in a single place. A few are described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html), but many, particularly the `Drawable` ones, are not.

However, there are many samples in the `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/$SDK/data/res` tree in your SDK installation (where `$ANDROID_HOME` is where you installed it and `$SDK` is the name of some SDK release, such as `android-2.1`).

Comment: yeah...the samples surely have the these xml elements... but it is frustrating not to have documentation..i mean looking at the samples i can get to know the elements use only..but more details like "selector" tag can be used for list, tab etc...
anyways thanks..